# prove the identity $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x+y,xy)dxdy=2\iint_{u^2>4v} \frac{f(u,v)}{\sqrt{u^2-4v}}dudv$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to prove that for all continuous(almost everywhere) function $f:G\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ this equality is true:

$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x+y,xy)dxdy=2\iint_{u^2>4v} \frac{f(u,v)}{\sqrt{u^2-4v}}dudv$$
where
$$G=\{(u,v):u^2>4v\}$$

This has something to do with change of variables, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

set $u=x+y$ and $v=xy$ , we have
$$u^2-4v=(x-y)^2$$
on the other hand
$$\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  \\
   \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|=\left| \begin{matrix}
   1 & 1  \\
   y & x  \\
\end{matrix} \right|=x-y\Rightarrow J=\frac{1}{x-y}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{{{u}^{2}}-4v}}
$$